# Inserting variable values into URL (or any string)

Tags: python, json, urllib

I am currently using `urllib` and `json` to perform a JSON request against a REST API as below:

```
import urllib, json

url = "http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?numrows=5&vendor_id=26&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=1&opec=1&opov=1&opcsrf=1&opfileinc=1&opgpriv=0&opsqli=1&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opginf=0&opdos=0&orderby=0&cvssscoremin=0"

response = urllib.urlopen(url)

data = json.loads(response.read())

for index, entry in enumerate(data, 1):
    print ('Item {}'.format(index))
        for name, value in entry.items():
            print '{}: {}'.format(name, value)
```

The API I am interacting with has the ability that if the `vendor_id` and `product_id` is changed it will as the values imply change the lookup it does for the vendor and the product and therefore a different response is generated.

I wanted to know therefore if it is possible to inject and alter in the url string the `vendor_id` and `product_id` numbers via a `raw_input` function or similar operation, whereby the user can input both of these numeric values? Is the use of the `%` operator incorrect in this case as this is for a string to be injected with a string?

Comment: How is `urllib` or JSON relevant here? Your question appears to be *"can you use Python's string formatting to format strings?"*, which has a pretty inevitable answer...

Comment: Are you trying to put different ids into the url string variable?

Comment: Yes @Zhiya. That is what I am researching if it is possible and attempting to do.

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. It's not clear where you've got stuck, exactly,  as your code so far neither takes any `raw_input` nor attempts to insert the results into the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String manipulation is easy:

```
vendor_id = raw_input("Vendor ID: ")
product_id = raw_input("Product ID: ")
url = ("http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?"
       "numrows=5"
       "&vendor_id={0}"
       "&product_id={1}"
       "&version_id=0"
       "&hasexp=1"
       "&opec=1"
       "&opov=1"
       "&opcsrf=1"
       "&opfileinc=1"
       "&opgpriv=0"
       "&opsqli=1"
       "&opxss=0"
       "&opdirt=0"
       "&opmemc=0"
       "&ophttprs=0"
       "&opbyp=0"
       "&opginf=0"
       "&opdos=0"
       "&orderby=0"
       "&cvssscoremin=0"
       .format(vendor_id, product_id))

>>> url
'http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?numrows=5&vendor_id=26&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=1&opec=1&opov=1&opcsrf=1&opfileinc=1&opgpriv=0&opsqli=1&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opginf=0&opdos=0&orderby=0&cvssscoremin=0'
```

Comment: Thanks for helping @Alexander. I have taken your string manipulation example and altered it to take the vendor ID as a raw_input which is exactly what I was looking for. Much Appreciated!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sorry if my question was not too clear. I am still learning my way around StackExchange and how best to present a question.